Print to Brother P-Touch using ESC/P from ASP.NET Webforms by IP
I am trying to print calibration labels to a Brother P-Touch P95NW.
The printer is configured with a static IP, I can ping it and print (by IP) from the P-Touch Editor.
To print from my webform I am trying to use code that works great for me with several different printers with varying languages.
Based on the printers developers manual, they supply a hex output as an example:

My desired code would send raw output to the printer.
Something like this:
    Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))
    Dim Label As String = "1B 69 61 00 1B 40 1B 69-6C D0 02 1B 24 3C 00 1B" &
                            "6B 00 1B 58 36 41 74 20-69 6F 75 72 20 73 69 64" &
                            "65 0C"
    clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Label))
    clientSocket.Close()

When executed there is no reaction from the printer at all.
Brother has some tech video's and in their examples they send the data in a text file, so I tried that. The file referenced has the same content as the string above.
    Dim filePath As String = "\\myserver\Systems\_MISC\bwtest.txt"
    Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.ASCII)

    Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))
    clientSocket.SendFile(filePath)
    clientSocket.Close()

Again I get the same result, nothing.
I also tried to use netcat to send the file, again with no results.
At this point I have to assume that I am missing something obvious with my output file or a configuration somewhere. I am printing on a .94" wide label with the same type of orientation as shown in their example.
Any advice appreciated!

It looks like you made a string representation of the hex then sent that.  I doubt that's what's requested, I would expect that the request is to send a binary version of the original command.  Depending on what form it takes, you might start out with a hex-encoded integer (leading &H), you might run a hex-encoded string through one of the Convert.ToInt family (available in widths from 16 to 64 I think), or you might use something like Convert.FromHexString (which might only be in .NET Core heritage versions of .NET).

Or you might use Encoding.GetBytes in a similar way to what you're doing right now, except on the original form of the command rather than a hex-converted form.

So the issue was definitely the format in witch I was sending data to the printer. The printer would not interpret the string and required a byte array to work.
Something like this works.
    Dim IP As String = "xxx.xx.xx.xx"
    Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))
    Dim Label As String = "1B 69 61 00 1B 40 1B 69-6C D0 02 1B 24 3C 00 1B " &
                            "6B 00 1B 58 36 41 74 20-79 6F 75 72 20 73 69 64 " &
                            "65 0C "
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = HexStringToBytes(Label)
    clientSocket.Send(byteArray)
    clientSocket.Close()

By using a function to do the conversion.
Function HexStringToBytes(ByVal hexString As String) As Byte()
    Dim result As New List(Of Byte)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To hexString.Length - 1 Step 3
        result.Add(Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16))
    Next
    Return result.ToArray()
End Function

In a real world application this isn't really practical since making changes would be difficult from the hex string.
You can do the conversion from the ESC/p code on the fly as well.
Dim myText As String = StrToHex("At your side")

Public Function StrToHex(ByRef Data As String) As String
    Dim sVal As String
    Dim sHex As String = ""
    While Data.Length > 0
        sVal = Conversion.Hex(Strings.Asc(Data.Substring(0, 1).ToString()))
        Data = Data.Substring(1, Data.Length - 1)
        sHex = sHex & sVal & " "
    End While

    Return sHex
End Function

The biggest hang-up here is realizing that items like FF and ESC are ASCII characters and not the text you are supplied.
